# Python: Reading individual elements of a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am attempting to read in individual elements of a file. In this example, the first element of each line is to be the key of a dictionary. The next five elements will be a corresponding value for said key in list form.

```
max_points = [25, 25, 50, 25, 100]
assignments = ['hw ch 1', 'hw ch 2', 'quiz   ', 'hw ch 3', 'test']
students = {'#Max': max_points}

def load_records(students, filename):
    #loads student records from a file
    in_file = open(filename, "r")
    #run until break
    while True:
        #read line for each iteration
        in_line = in_file.readline()
        #ends while True
        if not in_line: break
        #deletes line read in
        in_line = in_line[:-1]
        #initialize grades list
        grades = [0]*len(students['#Max'])
        #set name and grades
        name, grades[0], grades[1], grades[2], grades[3], grades[4] = in_line.split()
        #add names and grades to dictionary
        students[name] = grades
        print name, students[name]


filename = 'C:\Python27\Python_prgms\Grades_list.txt'
print load_records(students, filename)
```

The method I have now is extremely caveman, and I would like to know what the more elegant, looping method would be. I have been looking for a while, but I can't seem to find the correct method of iteration. Help a brotha out.

Comment: You don't need to comment every line especially when it's obvious wht the line does.

Comment: As an aside, these type of grade-keeping projects are my #1 example of how object-oriented programming can simplify code. Imagine instead having a list of `Student` objects, each one having an instance variable `grades` that is a list of `Assignment` objects that each have instance variables `max` and `score`. This problem suddenly becomes MUCH clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it:

```
def load_records(students, filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            name = line[0]
            students[name] = map(int, line[1:])
            print name, students[name]
```

It seems a bit strange that the `student` dictionary contains both the scores and a parameter `#Max` though - a key has two meanings, is it a student's name or parameter's name? Might be better to separate them.

Comment: The '#Max' would be equivalent to a student who scored perfect on every assignment. The reason for this is so that it will print before all other students when looping through keys.

Comment: I'm not clear on what map(int, line[1:]) does. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: ``line[1:]`` refers to the second items onwards in the list (i.e. the scores, skipping the first item which is the name), and ``map(int, line[1:])`` converts the scores to integers instead of being strings. If the scores aren't integer numbers, you need to change that to ``map(float, line[1:])``.

Comment: @user3271700 No problem. If this solves your problem, you can consider accepting the answer to close this question. This is how things work here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had an assignment similar to this last year.

```
def load_records(students, filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    s = ""
    while s != None: # loop until end of file is reached
        s = file.readline()
        # manipulate s how you need
```

Also, you should use inline comments like above, it makes the code much easier to read compared to how you have it now.